# __str__ function behaving differently in Pycharm and Vim editor

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5

```
class Point:
      def __init__(self, x, y, z):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.z = z
      def __str__(self):
            return f'point : ({self.x}, {self.y}, {self.z})' #works perfectly in pycharm but shows syntax error in vim
            return 'point' + ':' + '(' + self.x + ',' + self.y + ',' + self.z + ')' # shows error that cannot convert int to string implicitly

p1 = Point(4, 2, 9)
print(p1)
```

My desired output should be in the format `point : (4, 2, 9)`.

Doing the modifications in the `__str__` method but the return statements are not working in vim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python f-strings were only introduced in Python 3.6, so if you're using Python 3.5 they won't work.

The equivalent feature in Python before 3.6 is the `format()` method.

So instead of:

```
return f'point : ({self.x}, {self.y}, {self.z})'
```

You can use:

```
return 'point : ({self.x}, {self.y}, {self.z})'.format(self=self)
```

If you want to be compatible with Python 3.5 or lower.